# Shiv'a Veshishim Umeya - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows one hundred sixty-seven?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Megilas Esther has 167 Pesukim.

The Gematria of 167 is ונהפוך